# Unit Testing ASP.NET Generic Handlers without using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, generic-handler

I need to create Unit test cases for my ASP.NET generic Handler. My Handler code is as below:

```
    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            var data = context.Request.InputStream;
            //Here logic read the context.Request.InputStream
            //All the data will be posted to this Stream
            //Calling of business logic layer Methods
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to create the Unit test cases for this Handler. I have tried following ways to do unit test cases.

- Making an `HttpWebRequest` to this handle and writing all the data to request stream. I don't want to proceed with this as we have separate tool which makes `HttpWebRequest` to test all handlers
- Creating Unit test cases for Business methods but in this i am unable to check some logic written in handler level.

I have tried to Mock the HttpContext but it's not allowing to mock this (is it possible to to Mock HttpContent?). I tried
[this](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2011/12/07/Unit-Testing-ASPNet-Http-Handlers-and-a-discussion-of-Auto-Mocking-and-the-Testable-pattern.aspx) way but this needs modification to my handler also but i don't have provision to do this.

Finally my questions is, Is there any other way to unit test handler?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The article you linked to uses a very common approach - adding a new ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context) overload and moving your logic there. Is that really not a viable approach for your app?

Comment: @IanGilroy - Thanks for reply.. in this way i need to modify my Handler to add new overloaded ProcessRequest. My project contains almost 100 more handlers , for editing all these will take time that's why i am looking for any other solution which will not need modifications actual handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to mock the context is to create an additional method that uses an HttpContextBase and just forward a call from the interface method. The HttpContextBase can called using an HttpContextWrapper which would give you the possibility to mock the context

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       ProcessRequestBase(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }
    public void ProcessRequestBase(HttpContextBase ctx)
    {

    }
```

Which could be tested by hitting the ProcessRequestBase-method. We would have to assume that the ProcessRequestBase works as intended, but that's hard to avoid.
Then you can test it using calls like this

```
HttpContextBase mock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(); //or whatever syntax your mock framework uses
handler.ProcessRequest(mock.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I have tried this one but In this way i need to modify my Handler to add new overloaded ProcessRequest. My project contains almost 100 more handlers , for editing all these will take time that's why i am looking for any other solution which will not need modifications actual handlers.

Comment: If you're going to write tests for them anyhow, why not just do it one at a time? Perhaps by creating a common base class to make sure it works the same all over? Using a tool like Resharper or write a script to do/help with the change? Either way, there is no quick fix for testing 100 different classes